# Query Json data saved in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to query JSON data saved in postgres. 
This is how the table is created

```
CREATE TABLE ALARMDATA2(ALARM        CHAR(1300))
```

This is the JSON object:

```
{"delay_max": 0.0, "ts_errors": [{"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": true, "name": "SYNC", "is_priority2": false}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": true, "name": "BYTE", "is_priority2": false}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": true, "name": "PAT", "is_priority2": false}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": true, "name": "CC", "is_priority2": false}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": true, "name": "PMT", "is_priority2": false}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": true, "name": "PID", "is_priority2": false}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": false, "name": "TS", "is_priority2": true}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": false, "name": "CRC", "is_priority2": true}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": false, "name": "PCR", "is_priority2": true}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": false, "name": "ACC", "is_priority2": true}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": false, "name": "PTS", "is_priority2": true}, {"count": 0, "state": 0, "is_priority1": false, "name": "CAT", "is_priority2": true}], "is_stream_paused": false, "delay_min": 0.0, "ac_err": 0.0, "oj_err": 0.0}
```

I'd like to query based on "delay_max" (the first entry in JSON). I am using this query

```
SELECT ALARM->>'delay_max' AS delay_max FROM alarmdata2;
```

I think the query syntax is fine as per these links ([here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) and [here](https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/)) but I am getting this error

> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.

I've been searching for a while but I have not clue.
Any suggestions why ?

Comment: Never ever use `char()` and for JSON use - well - `json` (or `jsonb`)

Comment: *Almost* never use `char()` anyway in PostgreSQL. Unless you can know the size, it can't grow, and the input isn't whitespace padded on either side; or, if you want the whitespace padding (which is almost always bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the ALARM colum as type JSON or JSONB:

`CREATE TABLE ALARMDATA2(ALARM        JSONB)`

And then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix the problem

```
ALTER TABLE alarmdata2
ALTER COLUMN alarm
  TYPE jsonb
  USING alarm::jsonb;
```

## Or, work around it

```
SELECT ALARM::jsonb->>'delay_max' AS delay_max
FROM alarmdata2;
```